# How to query related objects in Loopback 4

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have two models Post and User.

I've marked userId property of post with belongsTo decorator

```
@belongsTo(() => User, {keyTo: 'id', name: 'user'})
userId: number;
```

but when I use include filter on post.

```
return await this.postRepository.find({
        "include": [{
            "relation": "user",
        }
        ]});
```

Loopback throws an error

```
Unhandled error in GET /posts: 500 Error: Relation "user" is not defined for Post model
at processIncludeItem (/node/posts/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/include.js:309:10)
at /node/posts/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/include.js:187:7
at /node/posts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3110:16
at eachOfArrayLike (/node/posts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1069:9)
at eachOf (/node/posts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1117:5)
at Object.eachLimit (/node/posts/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3172:5)
at Function.Inclusion.include (/node/posts/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/include.js:185:9)
at /node/posts/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/connectors/memory.js:510:33
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know inclusion of related Models is currently not implemented.
see the [Inclusion Issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1352) and [lack of features compared to previous version](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1920)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create relation by command:

`lb4 relation`

after that:

```
return this.postRepository.find(1, {include: [{relation: 'user'}]};)
```

You can refer here : https://strongloop.com/strongblog/inclusion-of-related-models/